# how to run a cmd file from matlab

Tags: matlab, cmd

I am trying to run a cmd file from MATLAB but unable to execute it. Can anybody see nay problem in the below code?

this is what I have inside my cmd file:

```
echo on
>test.log 2>&1 (
C:/testProj/Make/makeit.cmd param1
)
```

And this is the MATLAB code:

```
Out = 'C:/testProj/test.cmd';
system(Out);
```

But this actually does not run the cmd file.

Comment: for one Out must be a string. For further help it would be best if you report what is the actual error.

Comment: hi, there is no error. it just executes that line, but i dont see the output. the makeit.cmd is supposed to convert my c project into hex, If i run it manually it works fine.

Comment: well with `;` you suppress output. try this syntax: `[status,cmdout] = system(command)` and tell what it says.

Comment: the status is 1 and cmdout =


C:\Projekte>echo on 

C:\Projekte>(C:/testProj/Make/makeit.cmd param1 ) 1>test.log 2>&1

Comment: so 1 means error. Are you sure your script is ok? `echo on` more looks like sh and not like windows for me.

Comment: ya that is used to read the output messages from the command. But when i double click the batch file it runs without any problem.

Comment: so what does test.log say?

Comment: since the command is not run there is no log :(

Comment: i think its the problem because the directory it is pointing to in the console is different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well for somereason it would not run if i would give the complete path of the cmd in bat file. so I had a cd command to change the directory and then run. now it runs fine, Thanks all appreciate your help!

Comment: good you figured it out. You could mark this post as solution so later on people who have the same problem will find it.

Answer (score 0):

What about using eval, like this:

`eval(['!test.cmd']);`

I have succesfully used this to run .bat files (and this output of the .bat script showed in my matlab command line). I also found this [dos](http://www.mathworks.nl/help/matlab/ref/dos.html) command, but I am not sure if it works allright:

Comment: Well this dint work as well. Is it because i have a long path and hence the problem? i have tried with the double quotes too.

Answer (score 0):

You can just type the following strings to get things down:

```
!(c:/testProj/test.cmd)
```

This is actually no different from

`system('c:/testProj/test.cmd')`

I think you should check if the path is wrong. As to your code in the cmd file, that's beyond my ability to help.